Proving Varignon's theorem using vectors
Varignon's theorem assets that the midpoints of the sides of an arbitrary quadrilateral form a parallelogram. If the quadrilateral is convex or concave (not complex), then the area of the parallelogram is half the area of the quadrilateral. 
I want to prove that $Area(ABCD)=2Area(EFGH)$ using vectors.
Set $\vec{a}=\overrightarrow{AB}$, $\vec{b}=\overrightarrow{BC}$, $\vec{c}=\overrightarrow{CD}$. Hence,
$$
Area(ABCD)=Area(ABC)+Area(ACD)=\frac{1}{2}\|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}\|+
\frac{1}{2}\|(\vec{a}+\vec{b})\times\vec{c}\|
$$
On the other hand
$$
2Area(EFGH)=2\|(\frac{1}{2}\vec{a}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{b})\times(\frac{1}{2}\vec{b}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{c})\|=\frac{1}{2}\|(\vec{a}+\vec{b})\times(\vec{b}+\vec{c})\|
$$
Why these expression are equal?

It is to do with the distributivity of the cross product over vector addition. Try expanding (carefully) both expressions and then comparing them...

Thanks @Red Five, but the first expression is a sum of norm while the second is not (clearly $|x+y|\neq|x|+|y|$ in general).

Vectors $\vec a\times \vec b$ and $(\vec a+ \vec b)\times\vec c$ have the same direction (both perpendicular to the plane of the quadrilateral), that's why the sum of their norms is the same as the norm of their sum.
